# How to deal with Interops between 32-bit and 64-bit environments?

Tags: .net, com, interop, registry, 32bit-64bit

Short 2 questions, I cannot find clear answers after reading several topic/pages.

1. If I copied some interop dll to my computer, it's build to AnyCpu (checked with .net reflector) and if I want to reference to it in application build for 64 bit  (now I get an exception) - is registering it as 64 bit is enough (with regasm) - or maybe we do not register interops - only COM's?
2. If I have interop dll - can I get the original COM for which this interop was created (this would be useful to create another interop e.g. for 64 bit environment)?

**EDIT**: after @David response I checked one more option and unexpectedly it worked but now I am not sure what does it mean for this discussion and solution. Can anybody help to resolve this?

**What I did**:
I followed instructions from [here](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) and now object from COM does work with my 64 bit application! It might be tricky to do this manually for all objects (hundreds of them in interop) - is it correct way to deal with my Interop?

Regards,
jotbek

Comment: `regasm` is used when you create a library in .NET that you want to use from a COM application, not for when you have a COM library you want to use in .NET.

Comment: While using [DllSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691260(v=vs.85).aspx) does get around the bitness problem, its intended use appears to be isolation - keeping any problem in the COM DLL from affecting the main program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM servers (DLLs) are native code, so they can't cross bitness boundaries, i.e., 32-bit to 64-bit. Your .NET code needs to be compiled as x86 (well, at least the startup code does) in order to have a 32-bit process into which to load the COM DLL (unless the COM DLL is itself 64-bit, in which case your startup code needs to be compiled as x64).

An interop DLL is just a .NET assembly containing glue to call methods on COM objects. Knowing which COM DLL the interop DLL is for would not allow you to generate a working interop DLL with a different bitness.

Comment: So you say that flag checked with .Net reflector that my Interop dll is build for AnyCPU is irrelevant? Meaning that EVERY interop needs to be fixed for 32bit/64bit architecture - because it is the consequence of original COM bitness that Interop is connected?

Comment: @jotbek - Interop DLLs should be AnyCPU. What needs to match is the bitness of the COM DLL and whatever assembly your startup code is in. An AnyCPU assembly will run in whatever bitness the process is started in (that's why it's "AnyCPU" :). You can certainly build a 32-bit-specific interop DLL, say, but it's just extra work.

Comment: Ok, thanks so if I must run main process in 64 bit and I have AnyCPU Interop that is kind of adapter to orginal COM (that is 32 bit) so what are my options? I checked this as well and I know that surrogate process would work it is a little bit slow unfortunately, but what about RCW - Runtime Callable Wrapper - but for this I would need the original COM dll and from what you write it would not work as well because I would not be able to build RCW for 64bit when my original COM is x32?

Comment: There isn't any easy way to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process. You'd have to use a surrogate process. Also, RCW's are the objects contained in an interop DLL.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems that only reasonable solution is to create surrogate process when I do not have sources for native COM and talk with it via IPC/WPF. I also tried Ildasm this interop and again Ilasm as 64 bit - it succeeded but 64 bit app still refused to load such interop with exception that it is not properly registered - that's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: I'd guess that the COM DLL isn't "properly registered" because it's registered in the 32-bit area of the registry, not the 64-bit area. And that *is* proper, since it's a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: it seems so, when my application is built for 32 bit it works properly with that Interop dll - from what we discussed here it must be registered properly then - the main conclusion is that re-registering it would give nothing (even if it would be possible).

Comment: Please see the Edit section in my first post. Could you refer to this?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691260(v=vs.85).aspx. `DllSurrogate` is just a way to have Windows create the surrogate process for you.

Comment: You are right I manage to get this conclusions from several documents. Do you know if there exist any tool or way to create such surrogates automatically for all COM objects provided by Interop? I did not find anything that would to this (besides maybe dllhost?). Also thank you again for your reponses it took me 2 days to get to this :) and you have helped me a lot.

Comment: There won't be a way to do this for the COM objects of any group. What this registry key is doing is causing the system to put each such COM DLL in its own process, which is rather resource-intensive - the responsibility will be on the developer to decide which DLLs need this functionality and balance it against the overall system responsiveness.

Comment: @prprcupofcoffee : I agree, that AnyCPU is the best solution. The dll however has to be copied into `"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` and registered using `regasm` with `/tlb / codebase` as far as i spent some hours to find out.